# Material-ui close all other card content when clicking one

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, material-ui

I would like to close all other opened cards while I click another one, I would want something that works like Accordion Component.

My current code looks as below:

```
<List>
      {
        this.results.map((result: PTemplate, index: number) => {
          return (
            <ResultCard key={"row_"+index} result={result} id={index} initiallyExpanded={false}></ResultCard>
          )
        })
      }
      </List>
```

looks smth like this:

```
<Card key={'res_'+result.id} initiallyExpanded={initiallyExpanded} style={styles.resultInstance}>
    <CardHeader actAsExpander={true} showExpandableButton={true} style={resultTypeStyle}>
      <Flexbox>Header</Flexbox>
    </CardHeader>
    <CardText actAsExpander={false} expandable={true} key={'res_cont_'+result.id}>Description here</CardText>
  </Card>
```

Any idea how would I do this?

Comment: you need a state object to control which card is opened. you could take a look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: @MarsonMao Thanx, Yeah I already tried something like this but Card does not seem to have any action like OnChange or OnClick , idk how do I else make this work!

Comment: Oh! if that's the problem, then you can wrap <Card> with <ButtonBase> so it could be clickable